# Rearranging sums (by multiplying out)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I know that to reverse the summation requires the double sum to either be absolute convergent or non-negative (but in the second case, it may diverge to $\infty$)

I was wondering for something like this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n) \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} P(X=k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} g(n)P(X=k)$$

In what circumstances is such a multiplicative distribution over an infinite sum allowed?

Comment: you can always switch summation and multiplication by a number